# dict_keys & dict_values append to columns in existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

i got a dict with keys and values e.g.:

```
dict_1 = {'Dog': ['Dog'], 'Car': ['Cat']}
```

and a DataFrame

```
,name,values
0   Apple   [Apple]
1   Pear    [Pear]
2   Lemon   [Lemon]
```

i would like to add /append the dict to the columns in an existing dataframe

```
,name,values
0   Apple   [Apple]
1   Pear    [Pear]
2   Lemon   [Lemon]
3   Dog     [Dog]
4   Cat     [Cat]
```

I am desperate at this seemingly simple task. Could you please help me?

Comment: Does [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
for k, v in dict_1.items():
    temp = pd.DataFrame({"names": k, "values": [v]})
    df = df.append(temp)
```